# Will a synchronized block help me in this situation?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

`application.temporaryStory` is globally visible `Story` object that at least 2 threads can write to and read from.

In an adapter, I have this code;

```
        synchronized (this){
            if(application.temporaryStory!=null){ // Line A
                application.temporaryStory.setLastImageViewed(position); // Line B
            }
        }
```

This code is executed in the main thread.
Is it possible, in spite of the synchronized block, for a worker thread to null out the `application.temporaryStory` object between the check in line A and the code in line B?

Comment: if that worker thread doesn't synchronize on the same object as the thread which is executing Line A/B yes. all access to temporaryStory must be synchroinzed with the same object!

Comment: can I synchronize every read/write to application.temporaryStory on temporaryStory itself?

Comment: i think that should be possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to synchronize **all** reading and writing operations to the object on the same monitor object. Otherwise it *is* possible for other threads to change the value while the current thread is running. So I would suggest to use `application` here, since it seems to be the "owner" of `temporaryStory`:

```
synchronized (this){
    if(application.temporaryStory!=null){
        application.temporaryStory.setLastImageViewed(position);
    }
}
```

It would be even better when you would encapsulate `temporaryStory` somewhere (e.g. in application, but maybe there is a better place), so it is only accessible through synchronized methods.

But to do this, you need to move all code that needs to access `temporaryStory` in an atomic way to the encapsulating class. So the code from your example would need to move to the Application class:

```
public synchronized void setLastImageViewed(...) {
    if(application.temporaryStory!=null){ // Line A
        application.temporaryStory.setLastImageViewed(position);
    }
}
```

This code may or may not fit well with your existing application class. If you feel that it does not fit well there, create a new class and a new object that provide access to your temporary stories. Use this new class to synchronize all access to your temporary story object.

Comment: can I wrap the Story object that is temporaryStory in another object that synchronizes all read/write operations on it?

Comment: @J.K. yes, I just updated my answer. Will add a bit more details in a minute ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible: Due to the fact that that block is *externally* synchronized, it would be enough with an *unsynchronized* invocation to make it fail.

The root cause of it all is to have member variables publicly exposed. The good programming practices encourages to have all variables private, and expose them if necessary through public methods.

**Update**

So, if instead of a public variable `temporaryStore` you had one public  method for each operation required to be atomic, you could introduce internal synchronizations into those methods, protecting all possible access to the `temporaryStore` object.

In your case, you'd need:

```
public void setLastImageViewed(position)
{
   synchronized (this){
        if(application.temporaryStory!=null){ // Line A
            application.temporaryStory.setLastImageViewed(position); // Line B
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so if I had getTemporaryStory that returns story in a synchronized block, and setTemporaryStory that sets the story in a synchronized block, I'd have no problems?

Comment: This is not entirely correct. A getTemporaryStore method will not help with the update after read problem. You'd need to move all code that needs to run atomically to the class that encapsulates temporaryStory.

Comment: @LittleSanti undid my downvote since now your answer is correct :)

Comment: @David Tanzer Thanks a lot. You downvoted well at first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use an `AtomicReference` instead, you can get away without explicit synchronization:

```
public final AtomicReference<Story> temporaryStoryHolder = new AtomicReference<>();
```

(noting that it is `final`, so you can't null out `temporaryStoryHolder`, but you can still change its contents). Then

```
Story temporaryStory = temporaryStoryHolder.get();
if (temporaryStory != null) {
  temporaryStory.setLastImageViewed(position);
}
```